# Run two Magento Applications on one public IP using apache2

Tags: php, apache, magento, ubuntu, virtualhost

There are two Magento applications cosmetics and apparels. I want to run that both applications using apache2 on one public IP. 
So applications would be open with path like,

```
127.0.0.4/apparels
127.0.0.4/cosmetics
```

So, i have setup `VirtualHost` for both applications like in `000-default.conf` file at `etc/apache2/sites-available` in Ubuntu but its not working as i need,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/apparels/
  Alias /cosmetics /var/www/apparels/

  <Directory "/var/www/apparels">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/cosmetics/
  Alias /cosmetics /var/www/cosmetics/

  <Directory "/var/www/cosmetics">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help if anyone know.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give little more details like when you try and hit 127.0.0.4/apparels
127.0.0.4/cosmetics both these urls, currently what they redirect to?

Comment: When i will on `127.0.0.4/cosmetics`, it will run cosmetics application. But when i will write `127.0.0.4/apparels` in the url, the application will open with `127.0.0.4` but not with alias `127.0.0.4/apparels`.

Comment: You can use two subdomains ? (ie: cosmetics.mydomain.com and apparels.mydomain.com)

Comment: @Nolwennig will you please tell me how i can do that?

Comment: @rick in conf files in sites-enabled use ServerAlias cosmetics.mydomain.com for directory /var/www/cosmetics and apparels.mydomain.com for directory /var/www/apparels/

Comment: I write a quick answer for add an explanation => http://stackoverflow.com/a/34608177/4457531

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, you need to create 2 files.conf, in example: `010-cosmetic.conf` & `010-apparel.conf`

In `010-cosmetic.conf`, write something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias cosmetics.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/cosmetics/
  Alias /cosmetics /var/www/cosmetics/

  <Directory "/var/www/cosmetics">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in `010-apparel.conf`, write something like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias apparels.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/apparels/
  Alias /cosmetics /var/www/apparels/

  <Directory "/var/www/apparels">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to have /apparels in Alias for /var/www/html/apparels/ where currently you have specified /cosmetics

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apparels/
  Alias /apparels /var/www/apparels/

  <Directory "/var/www/html/apparels">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question. Both application is in `www` folder not in `html` folder.